# How can I formulate a fuzzy inference system to approximate the tangent function?

Tags: fuzzy-logic

Consider the function $f(x)=\tan(2x)$. How can I determine a fuzzy system that approximates $f(x)$? How to choose membership functions and how to determine fuzzy rules? Any help would be appreciated.